# In Japanese, why do certain consonants change depending on the vowel?

Tags: phonology, japanese, palatalization

I was wondering why in Japanese, certain consonants change depending on the vowel. For example:

Consonants that do not change:

- ka / ki / ku / ke / ko
- na / ni / nu / ne / no

Consonants that do change:

- sa / shi / su / se / so
- ta / chi / tsu / te / to

Is there an explanation of this phenomenon? Does it appear in other languages as well?

Comment: But they *do* change! /ki/ and /ni/ (and /hi/) are clearly palatalized/fronted; the Wikipedia article transcribes them as /n̠ʲ/ etc..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is a very common phenomenon - it's called [Palatalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization). It happens when a consonant is followed by a front vowel (e,i, etc). However:

- it does not happen to all consonants - depending on the language and its evolution only some consonants may be affected. (as in your example, k does not become ch)
- it does not happen with all front vowels. In Japanese it's only before `i`.

This can be found, in various variations, in many languages.

This explains only the change before "i". The explanation for tsu can be found in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology)

> /t, d, n/ are laminal denti-alveolar (that is, the blade of the tongue contacts the back of the upper teeth and the front part of the alveolar ridge) and /s z/ are laminal alveolar. Before /i/, these sounds are alveolo-palatal ([tɕ (d)ʑ n̠ʲ ɕ (d)ʑ]) and before /u͍/ they are alveolar ([ts (d)z n s (d)z]).

The latter phenomenon is rarer (I can't think of examples other than Japanese). But consonant changes that depend on the preceding or the following vowel are common.

Comment: This is not quite accurate. /k/ does in fact palatalize. /s/ and /t/ go even further and turn into a fricative and an affricate, respectively.

Comment: /k/ does become /ch/ in some Japonic languages. For example Okinawan.

Answer (score 6):

At least some dialects of French also affricate apico-dental stops before i and u.  Polish and Brazilian Portuguese affricate and palatalize t and d before i, and Polish palatalizes s in the same environment, distinguishing si from sz (see Schenker 1966).

With regard to Japanese, the phonetic situation is very interesting.  The affrication of t and d before all high vowels is the addition of a groove (down the middle of the tongue) articulation instead of a sudden release to the stop.  S appears to be unaffected, because it is already articulated with a groove.  All three are also palatalized or fronted (articulation shifted to the frontum of the tongue) before the front vowel i.